# Why were default camera settings changed in Blender 2.8?

Tags: camera

**Default settings:**

**v2.79:**
*Lens* 35mm, *Sensor* 32mm

**v2.8:**
*Lens* 50mm, *Sensor* 36mm

Just out of curiousity what is the reason for that change?

Comment: Mhhh, that's what I've found: https://developer.blender.org/rBc6a4b469e3ac8844dfd66ad03cee38a746e0e01a

Comment: I feel I heard somwhere (blender today?!?) that they changed the defaults to something more similar to the real world (36mm sensor is the full frame format and 50mm is one of the most often used lenses and is not deforming the objects as much as the 35mm).

Comment: In this video https://youtu.be/z6B2gt5PWdQ?t=131, Gottfried Hofmann from Blender Diplom explains his thought about those default.

Comment: And here's the commit of those changes: https://developer.blender.org/rBbcf6cc1f6b5f16ec37651ff6b0964fd91a60a59b

Comment: Same default in Maya

Answer (score 1):

50mm lens is much more versatile and allot closer to the "human eye lens". For beginners that don't know about the lenses yet it can also be quite frustrating when things look off.